# How to check if an ArrayBuffer is detached or transfered in JS?

Tags: javascript, buffer, web-worker, arraybuffer

I'm working with Web Workers and Buffers recently.

Now I have a buffer and I want to check the sixth byte using [SmartBuffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/smart-buffer). If that byte is 0, send to worker1. Otherwise, send to worker2.

```
const buffer = SmartBuffer.fromBuffer(someBuffer);
if(buffer.toBuffer()[5] === 0){
    worker1.postMessage(someBuffer, [someBuffer]);
}
if(buffer.toBuffer()[5] === 1){
    worker2.postMessage(someBuffer, [someBuffer]);
}
```

Since I use a transferable object, if the `someBuffer` has been transferred, I cannot access it in line 5 anymore. (It'll cause an error: `Cannot perform Construct on a detached ArrayBuffer`.)

I know that's a bad example, and I can simply use `else if` to prevent this error. But the question is: **Is there any way to know if a buffer has been transferred?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `byteLength` property of a detached ArrayBuffer and each typed array which uses this ArrayBuffer will be zero.

I'm not sure about the internals of the SmartBuffer library but this check should work:

```
someBuffer.byteLength === 0
```

This does of course not help if you want to check an ArrayBuffer which has an initial byteLength of zero. In this case nothing will change if it gets detached. But I think this is only a problem in theory.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the most reliable way to check if it was detached is to use a `TypedArray` constructor.

While all detached buffers will have `byteLength === 0`, an empty `ArrayBuffer` will too and is not considered to be detached.

```js
function isDetached(ab) {
  if(ab.byteLength != 0) {
     // detached buffers will always have zero byteLength
     return false;
  }
  try {
     new Uint8Array(ab);
     return false;
  } catch {
     // Uint8Array throws if using a detached buffer
     return true;
  }
}

const ab = new ArrayBuffer(0);
console.log('isDetached:', isDetached(ab)); // false
structuredClone(ab, { transfer: [ab] }); // detach buffer
console.log('isDetached:', isDetached(ab)); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

In Node.js it is possible, might be the same (or at least similar) for browsers.

Using `util.format()`, which is also used in `console.log`, the detached ArrayBuffer is stringified to something like

```
ArrayBuffer { (detached), byteLength: 0 }
```

So checking for `detached` in the formatted value will tell you exactly that.
Example:

```
function isDetached(buffer: ArrayBuffer): boolean {
  if (buffer.byteLength === 0) {
    const formatted = util.format(buffer)
    return formatted.includes('detached')
  }
  return false
}
```